# Template pattern matching

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Consider this class template:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2, bool B>
class SomeClass { };
```

Now, I'd like to provide two implementations based on `B==true` and `B==false`. That is, I'd like to say something like:

```
template <ANYTHING, ANYTHING, true> class SomeClass {
// First implementation
};

template <ANYTHING, ANYTHING, false> class SomeClass {
// Second implementation
};
```

How can this be done in C++(11)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With partial specialization:

```
// primary
template<typename X, typename Bool>
struct Foo;

template<typename X>
struct Foo<X, std::true_type> {};

template<typename X>
struct Foo<X, std::false_type> {};

// use
Foo<X, std::true_type> x;
```

I use a type-wrapper for `bool`, but you can also do that with
non-type template parameters:

```
// primary
template<typename, bool>
struct Foo;

template<typename X>
struct Foo<X, true> {};

template<typename X>
struct Foo<X, false> {};

// use
Foo<X, true> x;
```

Sometimes you can compute the value used for partial specialization
with meta-programming in the default argument:

```
// primary
template<typename X, typename is_integral_ = std::is_integral<X>::type>
struct Foo;
```

This makes the configuration variable overridable by user choice.

```
struct my {};
Foo<my, std::true_type> x;
```

To prevent that, dispatch through inheritance:

```
// primary, where Foo_impl is any of the above
template<typename X>
struct Foo : public Foo_impl<X> {};
```

Comment: Great, man! This answered my question. Thank you. Why do you use that wrapper?

Comment: Note that the first version won't work for `Foo<T, std::is_signed<T>>`. I don't know if that is desirable or not.

Comment: @pmr, No, I mean the first one. `std::is_signed<T>` derives from one of `std::true_type` or `std::false_type`, but that is not enough to match it on a template specialization.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Ah, of course. I frankly never consider that kind of use in my code because it adds a lot of bloat to save a few characters. Maybe I should add it.

Answer (score 4):

It's called *partial specialization*:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2> class SomeClass<T1 ,T2, true> {
// First implementation
};

template <typename T1, typename T2> class SomeClass<T1, T2, false> {
// Second implementation
};
```

As the name indicates it is related to (full) *specialization* which looks like this:

```
template <> class SomeClass<int, char, false> {
// dedicated version for T1=int, T2=char, B=false
};
```

---

Note that if most of the implementation is the same, you can also write a single generic version, where only that code which depends on the bool argument is delegated to a *trait* class. In this case, the trait class would be fully-specialized on a single argument.